# JavaScript Use Any Number

Tags: javascript, variables, numbers

I'm building a custom lightboxing system (because I don't like how any of the ones out there handle it), and I need a way to detect whether or not a lightbox is already opened.

What I'd like to do is this:

```
if (getElementById("lb" + ##).clientHeight > 0) {
  // do nothing
} else {
  // execute code
}
```

Where the ## represents any combination of any two numbers, so that if I have

```
<div class="lightbox" id="lb01">
  <!-- empty -->
</div>
<div class="lightbox" id="lb02">
  <!-- empty -->
</div>
```

I can detect if one of them is showing, and if it is, not open another one.

EDIT: I'd really prefer not to use jQuery, and this seems like it should be a lot easier than some of the answers I'm getting. I'm open to changing anything to make it work, none of these classes or IDs are final.

EDIT 2: Figured out a much simpler way to do this. I set up a global `var lb = 0;` and then detect the value of that variable, if it's equal to 0, it runs the function and changed the value to 1. When I run the closing function, it changes the value back to 0. This prevents it from having more than one open, without all that crazy JS stuff you guys where giving me.

Basically, the code now looks like this, and works exactly like I wanted.

```
var lb = 0;

function lightbox(id) {
  if (lb == 0) {
    lb = 1;
  } else {
    // do nothing
  }
}

function hideme(id) {
  lb = 0;
}
```

Comment: keeping track of all div elements in an array can be considered...

Comment: [RESISTANCE TO JQUERY IS FUTILE]

Comment: @Ates Goral are you going to make the jquery-women wear a `$('#niqab')` and do we all have to pray the `$('.Resigprayers')` 6 times a day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: if you open/close a box you could assign/change an attribute like `isOpen`:

```
[boxelement].isOpen = true/false
if ([boxelement].isOpen) { }
```

Option 2: work with classNames:

```
 [boxelemnt].className += ' open';
 if ([boxelement].className.match(/open/i)) { }
 //on close
 [boxelement].className = [boxelement].className.replace(/open/i,'');
```

Comment: This is what I ended up using, but a little bit differently. I put what I used in my original post.

Answer (score 2):

Use classes, or (if it is an option) [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: How do I modify classes with JS? All I can find information on is IDs.

Comment: To iterate over your lightboxes get their ids: `var lbs = document.getElementsByClass("lightbox"); for(var i=0; i<lbs.length; i++) { lbs[i].id; /* lightbox ID */ }`. To change a class: `element.class = "myNewClass";`

Comment: I feel like that's crazy overcomplicated. There should be an easier way to do this...

Comment: Actually that getElementsByClass thing looks promising if I could get it working. All I need to do is figure out the height of the lightbox class and that'd solve it.

Comment: @NeXXeuS - `class` is a reserved word in ECMAScript. The DOM related property is *className*. Also, the `getElementsByClassName` method is not supported by all browsers so a feature test and fallback should be provided.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a good option. Something along these lines may be what you're going for...

```
$('.lightbox').click(function() {
    $('.lightbox').removeClass('.active'); //remove from all .lightbox
    $(this).addClass('.active'); //add .active to the current element
}
```

This way only one will be active at a time. This is just the basic idea, your code will probably be more complex based on your DOM structure.

Answer (score 0):

I hate "lightbox" effects - they obscure the page content and make me wait to see the image while I watch some animation the developer thought I'd like to see (which is **really** annonying after the second or third time) - so consider carefully before deploying them.

Create an object to store references to the divs, then give them a className based on their status. To see if one or either are "active", check to see if they have the active status class. When making them active or dormant, set an appropriate class.

Some simple className utility functions:

```
function hasClassName(el, cName) {

    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)');
    return el && re.test(el.className);
}

function addClassName(el, cName) {

    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    if (!hasClassName(el, cName)) {
        el.className = util.trim(el.className + ' ' + cName);
    }
}

function removeClassName(el, cName) {

    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    if (hasClassName(el, cName)) {
        var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)','g');
        el.className = trim(el.className.replace(re, ''));
    }
}

function trim(s) {
  return s.replace(/(^\s+)|(\s+$)/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');
}
```

Use with the module pattern or whatever if you don't want them as globals.

Comment: The point isn't for a ton of content to be in crazy lightboxes, I just want them to show a larger version of certain pictures, instead of opening a new tab and taking the user away from the site. I don't really care for lightboxes either, but it's better than opening a new tab and confusing someone who's not very computer savvy.